# Else statement usage

Tags: php

I have a conflict regarding else condition. I can write a program in 2 ways.

1. Method 1

   ```
   $msg = '';
   if(cond)
   {
       $msg = 'success';
   }
   else
   {
       $msg = 'error';
   }
   ```
2. Method 2

   ```
   $msg = 'error';
   if(cond)
   {
       $msg = 'success';
   }
   ```

Can you please tell me which method is better and how? Thanks

Comment: How about `$msg = (cond) ? 'success' : 'error';`?

Comment: Second one is better, for sure. Less lines, same behaviour, no perform impacts.

Comment: In this case it looks like it makes no difference, but as a rule of thumb, I like to set the variable to either the "safer" or more likely condition, so if it becomes a long list of checks and I miss something, or something unexpected happens, it's at least got a default value.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown readability > number of lines.

Comment: There is no hard and fast rule here, its about developer preference and readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Between the two, I'd choose the first one.

```
$msg = '';
if(cond) { 
    $msg = 'success'; 
} else { 
    $msg = 'error'; 
}
```

This is readable and clearly conveys what it's trying to do.
If the condition is true, the message will be `success`. If not, the message will be `error`.

But for something really simple as above, I'd use a ternary statement instead. It's very useful and can cut down code,  but may make your code unreadable in some cases:

```
$msg = (cond) ? "success" : "error";
```

Pretty cool, right? Read more about [ternary operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) here.

Comment: As long as the condition is not overly complex I would say the ternary operator is far more readable and has the advantage of making it easy to see if the variable is initialized in all circumstances.

Comment: This is pretty subjective, but I agree that the first one is better.  If the block were to get long, someone unfamiliar with the code may "forget" that `$msg` had a "default" initialization.

Comment: @Nobody: I agree. Using ternary operator sounds like the best solution in *this* case.

Comment: @jedwards: Of course this is subjective (I think any answer to this question will be). If the blocks were to get long then the ternary operator would also be a much worse choice because it would also get longer and thereby lose its advantage.

Comment: @Nobody, sorry if I was unclear.  I meant something closer to "My opinion I'm about to pass-on is subjective, but..."  I was trying to explain my rationale for upvoting this answer.

Comment: @jedwards: I somewhat confused your comment as being an answer to mine. Now that I read it again I can't see why I did so. Yet, my statement is somewhat general enough to be not only directed to you :)

Comment: Being a bit picky I must say: The OP's first method also has a `$msg = '';` that you miss in your code. Do you do so on purpose and if so, would you please explain why?

Comment: @Nobody: Oops, I missed it. Thanks for reminding. I've added it back to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

```
$msg = (cond) ? 'success' : 'error';
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the second one is better cause it's less lines and it has a default behavior. No matter what, you know that $msg will contain something, even if you add other checks down the road. However, I would use the Ternary operator in this case:

`$msg = (cond) ? 'success' : 'error';`

Answer (score 1):

Code readability matters, so I'd use ternary operator when it really simplifies the look.
Consider this,

```
function foo($stuff) {

  $var = null;

  if ($stuff === true) {
    $var = true;
  } else {
    $var = false;
  }

  return $var !== null ? true : false;
}
```

Since in this case, `return $var !== null ? true : false` is pretty short, it can be considered as "easy to read and understand".

Consider this,

```
function foo($stuff) {

  $var = null;

  if ($stuff === true) {
    $var = true;
  } else {
    $var = false;
  }

  if ($var !== null) {
     return true;
  } else {
     return false;
  }
}
```

The same thing, but a little bit longer

Conclusion

- if a condition isn't that long, it's okay to stick with ternary operators (Because of readability). But if its not, then you'd better stick with `if/else`

---

Also you should call this thing "Approach", not a "method", because a method is a function within a class.